# findCategoryByName(String name) possible solution (Lambda expression shows error)? - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I have two entities with many to many relationship (Product, Category), all I want to do is to have a method in controller that will return me all products by some category name. I have two repositories (extends CrudRepository) and two services for both classes and I have ProductController.

ProductServiceImpl.java

[ProductServiceImpl.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeoXy.png)

I have tried to implement it in CategoryService like :

[CategoryServiceImpl.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUKLz.png)

And then to call this method in the ProductService implementation so I can return all the products with corresponding names but the lambda expression doesn't let me to return a category object neither to assign it to other Category object, any suggestions?

Comment: Please add those yet rather small code snippets directly here in your question, it makes a first overview over your exact issue much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you cannot modify external variables inside lambda (they should be at least effectively final, see [this](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/what-is-effectively-final-variable-of.html)).

As a workaround, you can replace `forEach()` with regular for or enhanced for loop.